# Typescript PropertyDecorator do not work as advertised

Tags: typescript

When I try to code a simple Property Decorator in typescript the PropertyDescriptor is always null. If I use the following code and compile it with:

```
node_modules/.bin/tsc -experimentalDecorators --target es5 test.ts
```

then the PropertyDescriptor of "somestate" is always null.

```
function test():any {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor):void {
    console.log("Descriptor %o", descriptor);
    };
}

export class TestClass {

    @test()
    public somestate: string;
}

new TestClass();
```

This behaviour does not change no matter what I chose as target.

The generated decoration call is actually, and that obviously will always be bot set.

```
__decorate([
    test()
], TestClass.prototype, "somestate", void 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU, this is the expected behaviour.

According to the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), **Property Decorators** section:

> NOTE  A Property Descriptor is not provided as an argument to a
>   property decorator due to how property decorators are initialized in
>   TypeScript. This is because there is currently no mechanism to
>   describe an instance property when defining members of a prototype,
>   and no way to observe or modify the initializer for a property. As
>   such, a property decorator can only be used to observe that a property
>   of a specific name has been declared for a class.